# Illegal invocation at elementClosest fullcalendar v4.3.1

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, lwc

I'm using fullcalendar library v4.3.1 inside a Salesforce LWC. All was working good in sandbox until I clicked inside an event and I get the following error:

```
aura_prod.js:999 Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
throws at https://mybts--partial.sandbox.my.site.com/....../fullcalendar/packages/core/main.js:126:30 TypeError: Illegal invocation
    at elementClosest (main.js:126:30)
    at DateComponent.isValidDateDownEl (main.js:4070:25)
    at DateClicking._this.handlePointerDown (main.js:1128:57)
    at applyAll (main.js:988:36)
    at EmitterMixin.triggerWith (main.js:3523:17)
    at EmitterMixin.trigger (main.js:3518:18)
    at HitDragging.handlePointerDown (main.js:988:35)
    at applyAll (main.js:988:36)
    at EmitterMixin.triggerWith (main.js:3523:17)
    at EmitterMixin.trigger (main.js:3518:18)
```

I've tried many times what I've found on other threads (for example: https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/4990). Many people has shared this solution:

At core/main.js line 126 change this:

```
function elementClosest(el, selector) {
  return closestMethod.call(el, selector);
}
```

To this:

```
function elementClosest(el, selector) {
 return el.closest(selector);
}
```

But that solution doesn't work for me. As I upload the library to the static resource with that change I get a loaded error and the fullcalendar library is not loaded as it can load the core/main.js.

I've tried also with other versions and I don't make it work.
Anyone can assist?

Change from a version to another.

Comment: Can you start tagging your questions properly please? I've had to edit all of them up to now. Thankyou.

Comment: Perhaps because all the tags that I have tried to put do not allow me to do so. Thank you @ADyson

Comment: Does the question editor give an error message or something, when you try to add more tags? It should be possible to use all tags.

Comment: It's was actually a message saying something like the tag has not enough reputation. So, maybe I was choosing wrong tags. But it didn't seem that way to me.

Comment: Do you mean it told you that you don't have enough reputation to _create_ a tag? Because there is no need to create a new tag for this, you can just use the existing ones (like I added above). You can search for tags, and please ensure you get the spelling correct so it doesn't think you are trying to make a new one! As far as I know, and from my research, there is no reputation limit on who can make use of existing tags.

Comment: I am speaking from memory. I will make sure about tagging when I come back to ask a question. @ADyson, regarding my question above and as I see you have fullcalendar silver-badge, you know something about the error I've asked? Thank you.

Comment: For the question itself, the error seems to be due to including it in a salesforce component, rather than anything because of fullCalendar itself? I have no experience with salesforce stuff. If I was to make a demo using only fullCalendar, this issue would not occur. So I'm not sure I can be much help. That's why I wanted you to tag it correctly, so that with the salesforce/lwc tags added, there's more chance someone with experience of that environment might be able to suggest something.

Comment: That's make so much sense. Thank you for your help @ADyson!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION**:
I’ve managed to get this works. I just realised I was not setting the path static source correctly.

I confirm this solution works for the fullcalendar library inside a lwc.

Change to this at line 126 of core/main.js:

```
function elementClosest(el, selector) {
 return el.closest(selector);
}
```

Then, you’ll probably have to do the same with `function elementMatches()` just below `function elementClosest()`. I had to do it and it worked:

Change this:

```
function elementMatches(el, selector) {
 return matchesMethod.call(el, selector);
}
```

To this:

```
function elementMatches(el, selector) {
 return el.matches(selector);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the library with no changes, but enabling the Lightning Web Security Worked for my:

Setup > Session Settings > Lightning Web Security > Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components

IMPORTANT!! Enabling this option may impact in other components or functionalities of your org, so is much better if you make a full regresion test in your sandbox.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc8oX.png)